# Laravel Eloquent query from MySql

Tags: php, laravel

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE uuid LIKE '%10%' AND 
(id in(SELECT `with` FROM connected_people WHERE `is`=1) 
or id in (SELECT `is` FROM connected_people WHERE `with`=1));
```

I want to run this query using Eloquent But I don't have clear idea how to do.

```
User::where('uuid', 'LIKE', "%10%")->get();
```

Can anyone teach m e how to da this is Laravel.

Comment: You might want to declare a relationship in the `User` model with the `connected_people` table. I can give you a more elegant answer than the one already posted if you share with us your `connected_people` schema.

Comment: connected_people.is = user.id
connected_people.with=user.id

It is like which are the users connected with other people like facebook friend list. I want to display suggestion for the usernames which is in the user friend list (connected_people table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User::where('uuid', 'LIKE', "%10%")->where(function($query) use($id){
      $query->whereRaw('? IN (SELECT `with` FROM connected_people WHERE `is`=1)', [$id])
            ->orWhereRaw('? IN (SELECT `is` FROM connected_people WHERE `with`=1)', [$id]);
})
->get();
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a pivot table. Even if this somehow works, it might not be the best solution for his problem.